# Having problems using Pace.js with Flask templates

Tags: javascript, python, flask, progress-bar

I have a html page that is return by Flask templates, the loading takes 2 minutes, so I tried to use Pace.js to implement a progress bar.

here is my project structure:

```
project
   -static(folder)
        -js(folder)
             -pace.js
        -css(folder)
             -other.css
             -dataurl.css
   -templates(folder)
        -index.html
   -run.py(file)
```

index.html

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Popular Flickr Camera</title>
     <script language="JavaScript" src="static/js/pace.min.js" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/dataurl.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css" />
  </head>

<body>
    <table style="width:300px">
    <tr>
      <th>Rank</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Sensor Resolution</th>
      <th>LCD Size</th>
      <th>Weight</th>
      <th>Lens Mount</th>
    </tr>

    {% for brand in brands %}
        {% for model in brand.models %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{brand.rank}}</td>
          <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
          <td>{{model.name}}</td>
          <td>{{model.type}}</td>
          <td>{{model.resolution}}</td>
          <td>{{model.lcd}}</td>
          <td>{{model.weight}}</td>
          <td>{{model.lens}}</td>
        </tr>
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Html have no problem loading the "other.css" aloe,

but after I added pace.js resources (pace.min.js and dataurl.css), the website is blank, and the log in the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Feb/2014 11:08:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `src` and `href` attributes be pointing at `static/pace.min.js` and `static/dataurl.css` rather than at `static/js/pace.min.js` and `static/css/dataurl.css` that you have in your pasted template code?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that in the question.. I do have these 2 folders created. :p

Comment: Is `dataurl.css` in `/js/` or `/css/` ... your directory layout says one thing and your template code says the other :-)

Comment: corrected again :( ...

Answer (score 0):

If it takes 2 minutes, you probably should fix it, not add a crutch to it. Your loop shouldn't be a slow operation.

That said, `language` is deprecated and you should close your `<script>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/pace.min.js"></script>
```

Yes, this is a bit weird, but some browsers don't understand the `<script />`.

I didn't found HTML5 grammar, but HTML4.1 says:

> Start tag: required, End tag: required

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1